# TabBarView dynamic update List

Tags: dart, flutter

I have multiple `TabBarView` which generates dynamic Products `List`

```
TabBarView(
     controller: categoryTabController,
     children: List<Widget>.generate(categories.length,
               (index) => Products(categories[index])),
         ),
```

I have another TextField widget and when I type something I would like to update `List<Widget>` inside `TabBarView`, with new `Products(categories[index]))` List content.

```
TextField( onChanged: (text) {
           // need to update List<Widget> in above TabBarView
          },
       ),
```

how can I acheive it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do so using setState

```
TextField(
      onChanged: (text) {
        setState(() {
          userSearch = text;
        });
      },
```